# CSS display problem with Wordpress, i tried a piece of code but didnt work

Tags: wordpress

I have a css problem with my WordPress website and I couldn't figure it out.

Could anyone give me some help please?

```
    .lazyload.img-responsive.wp-post-image
{
    width="1200" !important;
}
```

I tried this piece of code but didn't work.

Please see attached screenshots for the problem.

My website is [this](https://azdc.com.au/#wpestate_sh_anime_342)

Thank you.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdCeq.jpg)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knOl4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
img.lazyload.img-responsive.wp-post-image {
width: 100% !important;
```

}

add the above css and image will be shown in exact posititon

Comment: Thank you so much Anjali, I tried many code didnt work, but this one works perfectly.